# IIS Hosted WCF without DLL

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-7.5

Is it possible to host a WCF (.NET 4) service in IIS (7.5 onwards) without having to compile the service to a DLL?

Is it just possible to use the .SVC, .SVC.CS and the Interface.CS files?

Just out of curiosity...?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, if you start with the right kind of project. Basically, anything created as a "Web Site" instead of a "Web Application Project" in Visual Studio should work, though you probably won't get as much help from VS on getting it done.